# Update multiple records in table selected with checkboxes - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have a table that list all the article records, each row have a checkbox. Users can select multiple articles and choose spesific action to the selected record using checkboxes . Similar like table for user with admin roles. 
User can select action from dropdown menu something like this

```
With Selected : - Delete Articles
                - Publish Articles
                - Unpublish Articles
```

My question is how to connect these menu to the correspond method in the controller?

```
resources :articles do
    collection do
      delete 'delete_multiple'
      patch 'publish_multiple'
      patch 'unpublish_multiple'
    end
  end
```

controller

```
def delete_multiple   
    Article.destroy(params[:article_ids])
end

def publish_multiple  
    Article.where(id: params[:article_ids]).update_all(published: true)
end
```

right now i only can connect one of these menu (delete_multiple) by using form_tag to submit the selected ids

```
    <%= form_tag delete_multiple_articles_path, method: :delete, id: 'form-listing' do %>
    <table >
         <th>Tittle</th>
         <th>Content</th>
         <th></th>
         <td><%= article.tittle %></td>
         <td><%= article.content %></td>
         <td><%= check_box_tag "article_ids[]", article.id ,false %></th>
   </table >
  <%= end %>
```

and using link_to to execute form submit

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><%= link_to 'Delete Selected', '#', :onclick => '$('#form-listing').submit();', %></li>
   <li>Publish Articles </li>   #? what to put here?
   <li>Unpublish Articles</li>  #? what to put here?
 </ul>
```

any advice guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually done like this: you have a single action for all operations with multiple records. When you choose the operation the form is submitted with a corresponding value.

```
# routes.rb

resources :articles do
  collection do
    patch 'batch_operation'
  end
end

# controller

def batch_operation   
  case params[:operation]
  when "delete"
    Article.destroy(params[:article_ids])
  when "publish"
    Article.where(id: params[:article_ids]).update_all(published: true)
  # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, is it OK to use patch for delete operation ?

Comment: Yes, it is fine. It is just a convention (recommendation) for typical cases which is not mandatory